# CustomWritable objects resulting in test case failure

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I changed the Normal `IntWritable` to appropriate `CustomerWritable` class , since then my test case is failing. What am i doing wrong here?

```
/*
this is my customWritable
*/
        package hadoop.mapreduce;


    import java.io.DataInput;
    import java.io.DataOutput;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;

    public class BidPriceCustWritable implements WritableComparable<BidPriceCustWritable> {

            private  Text cityId;
            private  Text osName;
            private  IntWritable bidPrice;

            public Text getCityId() {
                return cityId;
            }

            public void setCityId(Text cityId) {
                this.cityId = cityId;
            }

            public Text getOsName() {
                return osName;
            }
    //
            public void setOsName(Text osName) {
                this.osName = osName;
            }

            public IntWritable getBidPrice() {
                return bidPrice;
            }

            public void setBidPrice(IntWritable bidPrice) {
                this.bidPrice = bidPrice;
            }

        //hithihi
            public BidPriceCustWritable() {
                super();
                this.cityId = new Text("");
                this.osName = new Text("");
                this.bidPrice = new IntWritable(0);
            }
            // hiihioiii
            public BidPriceCustWritable(Text cityId, Text osName, IntWritable bidPrice) {
                super();
                this.cityId = cityId;
                this.osName = osName;
                this.bidPrice = bidPrice;
            }

            @Override
            public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cityId.write(out);
                osName.write(out);
                bidPrice.write(out);
            }

            @Override
            public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cityId.readFields(in);
                osName.readFields(in);
                bidPrice.readFields(in);
            }

            @Override
            public int compareTo(BidPriceCustWritable o) {
                     return this.getBidPrice().compareTo(o.getBidPrice());

            }
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return osName + "," + bidPrice;
            }
        }


Expected output is 

mapDriver.withOutput(new Text("daxinganling"), new BidPriceCustWritable(new Text("daxinganling"), new Text("WINDOWS_XP"), new IntWritable(294)));
            mapDriver.withOutput(new Text("huainan"), new BidPriceCustWritable(new Text("huainan"), new Text("WINDOWS_7"), new IntWritable(277)));
```

But it is failing. I debugged the issue everything working as expected but test case is failing.

Comment: Missing expected output (huainan, WINDOWS_XP,294) at position 0, got (jinzhongshi, WINDOWS_XP,294)., 
          * Missing expected output (daxinganling, WINDOWS_7,277) at position 1, got (huainan, WINDOWS_7,277).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have keys mismatch in result log. Check your code.
2. Also, as I can see, you didn't override *equals()* and *hashcode()* methods in your custom Writable type. Without that you will get wrong results.